# mongoose connection url showing malformed error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using following code to connect:

```
mongoose.connect(dbConnection, dbOptions, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR connecting to: ' + dbConnection + '. ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to: ' + dbConnection);
    }
});
```

But Unable to connect getting following error:

> URIError: URI malformed

Please help me to resolve this.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you show us this `URI`?

Comment: You provided no data we can inspect

Comment: ERROR connecting to: mongodb://(xxx)[yyyy$%^]@xxxxx:27017/admin/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that (from [connection string spec](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/connection-string/connection-string-spec.rst)):

> If the username, or password section contains a percent sign ("`%`"), an
>   at-sign ("`@`") or a colon ("`:`") it MUST be URL encoded.
>
> If the user information contains an at-sign ("@") or more than one
>   colon ("`:`") then an exception MUST be thrown informing the user that
>   the username and password must be URL encoded.

try with `encodeURIComponent()`

Comment: I tried the same, but fail to connect it.. Is there any version issue with mongoose ?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely not related to mongoose. It could be the specified HOST parameter that has a malformed URL, or the error is caused by another section of code.